# ActiveRecord query all the first items of a unique has-many association

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am having problems to create a Rails ActiveRecord query that retrieves the first Item by unique Activity considering a creation time internal. I also need the values available in ItemStat that is why the includes.

The current method implementation is working, but it is poor and needs optimization.

This is my analogue model:

Activity:

```
class Activity < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :items
end
```

Item:

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :activity
  has_one :item_stat
end
```

ItemStat:

```
class ItemStat < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :item
end
```

Current working method (activities_id are all activities available by an user):

```
def self.first_items_by_unique_activity(activities_id, time_begin, time_end)
  items = Item.includes(:item_stat).where(:activity_id => activities_id, :created_at => time_begin..time_end)

  #make the first item unique by activity
  uniques = {}
  items.each do |item|
    identifier = item.activity_id
    uniques[identifier] = item if uniques[identifier].nil?
  end   

  uniques.values
end
```

Thanks any help!